Quarkus with Panache Reactive - Test Unit with mockito
you developed a service in quarkus with reactive panache.
When I run testUnit I get a connection error to the database, despite using Mockito. I would appreciate your support to solve this error. I already tried the profiles in my application.yml but it still gives me the error.
import io.quarkus.test.InjectMock;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.vertx.RunOnVertxContext;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import junit_utils.ResourceUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

@QuarkusTest
@DisplayName("UserControllerTest - Integration Test")
class UserControllerTest {

    private static final String REQ_REGISTER_USER = "userRegister.json";

    private static UserRequest userRequest;

    @InjectMock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setupBeforeClass() {
        userRequest = ResourceUtil.mapFileToObject(ResourceUtil.DIR_REQ_REGISTER_USER,
                REQ_REGISTER_USER, UserRequest.class);
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Tests of operation 'registerUser'")
    class RegisterUserTest {

        @Test
        @RunOnVertxContext
        void register() {

            when(userRepository.persist(any(User.class)))
                    .thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(new User()));

            given()
                    .body(userRequest)
                    .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .when().post("/usermanagement/v1/register")
                    .then()
                    .assertThat()
                    .statusCode(201);
        }
    }
}

The error:
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:5432
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:339)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <201> but was <500>.

I tried quark profiles, but it didn't work. Reviewing the documentation https://es.quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache, I have done as indicated. Additionally, I use the repository pattern.

Can you share your service please? Maybe you call another method of the UserRepository

Does @QuarkusTest create and inject mocks? Normally, for @InjectMocks to work you need @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) for Mockito annotations to work
